# Create normal user and install SSh

Tags: server, ssh

I have created user with `sudo useradd cloudera`, User created successfully. Now I want to install ssh in `cloudera` user. If I execute

```
cloudera@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install ssh
[sudo] password for cloudera: 
cloudera is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

Now How to install ssh in newly added user?

Comment: Installation of ssh is not use specific. Install it using your primary user, the one you used to create cloudera. Then all users including cloudera will have access to ssh.

Comment: SSH is installed globally, not "in" any user. So just install with your existing admin account.

Comment: Read `man sudoers`, you must add `cloudera` to the `sudo` system.

Comment: How to add users to sshd is well documented here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/16650/create-a-new-ssh-user-on-ubuntu-server?rq=1

Comment: Do you want the server so you can connect FROM another PC or only use the SSH client to connect TO another PC?

Comment: @waltinator will it also be ok if OP adds an exception for user `cloudera` in using the `ssh`  command in the sudoers file

Answer (score 1):

When you ran `sudo adduser cloudera`, you used `sudo`. I am going to refer to this as the primary user.

## If you already have `ssh` installed

If you already have `ssh` installed, you shouldn't need to do anything. You should be able to `ssh` into it directly.

## If you don't have `ssh` installed

Install it in the primary user with the command `sudo apt-get install openssh-server`. This will install it system-wide, enabling it for all users.

## If you don't know whether you have `ssh` installed

Run `dpkg -L openssh-server`. If there is any output, you have it installed. Otherwise you don't.

Comment: Still not clear if the OP wants the server or only use the client...

Comment: @derHugo true... I made an assumption based upon what he was saying

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the comments and answers already posted here is a clarification.

From whichever user you executed the command

```
sudo useradd cloudera
```

that user obviously have super user privilege.

So, from the new user most probably you could use ssh, as it might be there already installed.

Else, you have three options:

(1) From the user which created "cloudera" install ssh using `sudo`

(2) Add "cloudera" to sudoers and proceed.

(3) Simply type `su` and provide the super user password. Then proceed to install ssh.

Comment: Please also add the relevant commands to your options! `sudo apt install openssh-server`, `sudo adduser cloudera sudo` and format code as code using the `{}` in the editor